# Pasar valor de C# a Python con Dynamic

Tags: python, c#

Tengo un Script en python para fusionar archvivos PDF de un directorio, desde C# pretendo pasar la ruta del directorio que el usuario seleccione, el Script funciona bien pero en C# recibo el error:

> **IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named 'os''**

Hice una prueba con un Script simple de Pytho que imprime mensaje por consola y sin problermas paso el mensaje desde C# a Python, pero con el Script del PDF me envia ese error, ¿alguna sugerencia como resolver este problema?

En Python:

```
from os import listdir, mkdir
from os.path import isfile, join, exists
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

def merge_pdfs(path):
```

En C#:

```csharp
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace TestToolsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string pathPY = @"C:\Users\MiUsuario\source\PDF_join.py";
            ScriptRuntime py = Python.CreateRuntime();
            dynamic pyProgram = py.UseFile(pathPY);
            pyProgram.merge_pdfs(txtParametro.Text);
           
        }
    }
}
```

Espero me pueda ayudar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: podemos suponer que el script en python, mas alla de la llamada desde c# funciona???? porque el error parece de python,, no de c#

Comment: @gbianchi 
El Script de Python ejecutado en Python funciona sin problemas.
Las librerias que tengo en Python las he agregado a la pregunta.

Comment: voy a tirar al aire algo.. puede ser que fallen los import, porque la ruta donde esta ejecutando el py c#, no sea la misma donde estas probando el script???

Comment: @gbianchi el Script lo tengo en la carpeta BIN de C#, a eso te refieres?

Comment: claro.. y de donde tiene que hacer los imports??? estan ahi mismo?? si lo ejecutas en esa carpeta funciona?? y ojo, porque que este ahi, no quiere decir que c# lo ejecute en esa carpeta... la carpeta de ejecucion de c# puede ser otra.. pero estoy hablando sin saber eh..

Comment: @gbianchi no pude solucionar el problema por lo que opte en lugar de pasarle parametros directamente de C# creo un fichero de texto con los parametros que requiero y leo estos desde el Script de Python.